# Weber-Hermite differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, parabolic-pde, hermite-polynomials

I was solving a quantum mechanics problem (harmonic oscillateur) and i need to solve this Weber-Hermite differential equation in an analytic method:
$$y"-x^2(y)=0$$
I know the solution of this equation is the parabolic cylinder function but i need to solve it analyticaly (to understand how they get the solution)
And thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

*I do not know if this answers the question.*

The general Weber differential equation (the solution of which being $D_\nu (x)$) is
$$y''+y \left(\nu +\frac{1}{2}-\frac{t^2}{4}\right)y=0$$ So, for your case, $\nu=-\frac{1}{2}$ and you need to redefine $x=t \sqrt 2$ to get your equation.